# Scheme: 3 numbers in a row, implementation

Tags: list, scheme

Currently I have a list of elements (1 2 1 2 2 0 0 1 0).

The point of the function I'm trying to write is that it should display a possibility that would show 3 of the same number in a row (which would be a 'winning' case).

The output I would want is (1 2 1 2 2 ***2*** 0 1 0). 
The function, when called, would be in the format of 
(display (next 2 (list)))

I'd assume I'd take the car of the list and if there's a way to store/remember the car I got (in case I call for it again and want to check if it matches).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The closest thing to a basic loop is the *named let* construct. Here's a simple implementation that works for your problem:

```
(define (next e lst)
  ; l1 : part of the list already processed (reversed)
  ; l2 : part of the list still to be processed
  ; c-2: element before previous
  ; c-1: previous element
  ; res: result (list of winning cases
  (let loop ((l1 null) (l2 lst) (c-2 null) (c-1 null) (res null))
    (if (null? l2)
        (reverse res)
        (let ((ca (car l2)) (cd (cdr l2)))
          (loop (cons ca l1) cd c-1 ca
                (if (and (= ca 0) (= c-2 e) (= c-1 e))
                    (cons (append (reverse l1) (cons c-1 cd)) res) ; build winning case
                    res))))))
```

then

```
> (next 2 '(1 2 1 2 2 0 0 1 0))
'((1 2 1 2 2 2 0 1 0))

> (next 2 '(1 2 1 2 2 0 2 2 0))
'((1 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 0) (1 2 1 2 2 0 2 2 2))

> (next 1 '(1 2 1 2 2 0 1 1 0))
'((1 2 1 2 2 0 1 1 1))
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I have a question though, if I want to replace it with letters (like a, b, c) how can I make it work so that it doesn't say (for something such as next a '(a b...)) that a is an unbound variable? Curious, but very well explained :)

Comment: In case of letters, what will represent the empty place - also 0?

Comment: Can it work with something such as 'e' for the empty spot? If not, just curious. Finally, how would I modify the existing code if I'd like to stop a player from having 3 in a row, let's pretend 1 is player 1 so that (next 1 '(1 2 1 2 2 0 0 1 0) returns (1 2 1 2 2 **1** 0 1 0)?